# Autocorrelation

Tags: statistics

My statistic skills is a bit a rusty. I have struggled with this in some time now. My question is:

I have this random process defined as $X(t) = A\cos(\omega_0t+x)$, where $A$ and $\omega_o$ are constants, and x is a random variable uniformley distrubted over the interval $ (- \pi , \pi)$. Let $Y(t) = X^2$ be the random process define the energy of the signal.

To find the autocorrelation function you can do the following:

$E[Y(t)]= E\{A^2\cos^2(w_ot+x) \} = A^2E \{1/2(1+\cos(2\omega t + 2 x)) \}.. $ The following step is what I don't understand. How does the $1$ disappear? 
$...= \frac{A^2}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}E \{\cos(2 \omega t + 2 x ) \} = \frac{A^2}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expectation is linear, so you can pull the 1 out. 1/2 is a constant, so the expectation $E(1/2)$ is 1/2.
\begin{align}
A^2E\{\frac{1}{2}(1+cos(2ωt+2x))\}=&A^2\left(E\{\frac{1}{2}*1\}+E\{(\frac{1}{2}cos(2ωt+2x))\}\right)\\
=&\frac{A^2}{2}+A^2E\{(\frac{1}{2}cos(2ωt+2x))\}\\
=&\frac{A^2}{2}
\end{align}